# CNN Regression predicts the same value for each test image.

Tags: deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, convolution

So just a set up of the problem I am trying to solve. I have around 200k 64x64x3 RGB images of patches of terrain that a robot drove over. Each patch has a corresponding label of what the roughness of that image patch is. The roughness values range from 0-160. The data was collected with the robot driving at varying speeds, hence the range of the roughness values. My aim is to be able to predict the roughness of a patch. I am using the VGG-16 network, with the last layer modified to do regression. My batch size is 1024, the loss is mean sqaured error, the optimize is rmsprop. The network is shown below. My problem is that after training, the network predicts the exact same value for each test image. Another point to note is that the training loss is always higher than the validation loss which is odd. Lastly I tried with other optimizers such as SGD and Adam, as well as varying batch sizes. Right now I am trying to train the network from scratch but it does not seem too promising. I am not sure what is going wrong here, and I would really appreciate any help I can get. Thanks

```
 if input_tensor is None:
    img_input = Input(shape=input_shape)
else:
    if not K.is_keras_tensor(input_tensor):
        img_input = Input(tensor=input_tensor, shape=input_shape)
    else:
        img_input = input_tensor
# Block 1
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block1_conv1')(img_input)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block1_conv2')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block1_pool')(x)

# Block 2
x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block2_conv1')(x)
x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block2_conv2')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block2_pool')(x)

# Block 3
x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv1')(x)
x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv2')(x)
x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv3')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block3_pool')(x)

# Block 4
x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv1')(x)
x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv2')(x)
x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv3')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block4_pool')(x)

# Block 5
x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block5_conv1')(x)
x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block5_conv2')(x)
x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block5_conv3')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block5_pool')(x)

x = Flatten(name='flatten')(x)
x = Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc1')(x)
x = Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc2')(x)
x = Dense(1,name='regression_dense')(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your explanation you have roughness values ranging from 0 to 160. Normalize these values in [-1, 1]. You can stick to your linear activation function in the last layer. 
But in general I think you can solve this problem with a much shallower architecture with just a fraction of parameters.

Cheers